# PHP Desktop Z-index

Tags: php, html, css, phpdesktop

I downloaded the PHP Desktop application from https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/wiki/DownloadMSIE, and paste www folder to the downloaded file. I am getting issue in z-index. Select Box appears first and Menu appears back. It is working fine in all the browsers but not in Desktop. The style for Menu,

```
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
```

Please help me in fixing it. 
Thanks..

Comment: Hello @user2281200, What do you mean by "Desktop" ?

Comment: Do you mean localhost???

Comment: try making it `z-index: 1000;`

Comment: @ Arqetech, We are converting the web appln to Desktop appln. Desktop means I dont mean the localhost, the desktop appln

Comment: Ooops! My bad :) But have you tried using the `z-index: 1000;` if that does not work try increasing It even more.

Answer (score 0):

the box which you want to display first give ithen

```
z-index:9999999;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP Desktop MSIE by default embeds IE 7.0. Maybe the old version of IE is cause of the issue. To use a newer version of IE embedded read this: https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/wiki/MSIEengine#How_to_use_a_newer_version_of_IE_engine